# Site not working on iphone/ipad.. Resize issue

Tags: jquery, iphone, css, wordpress

Is there an alternative to using a jquery plugin to resize videos for mobile (IOS) in a responsive design? Css maybe? Im using a wordpress theme and the video i added is messing it up

http://speedsociety.com/

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: im wondering if i can just fix this with margins? take a look at my url, i guess i dont need the video to resize as long as it loads...

Comment: It's always preferable to post your code in the question. Ideally, you should strip that code down to the bare minimum needed to reproduce the problem you're experiencing. Linking to the active site is bad because (a) the other site might go down for any number of reasons, (b) the code on the other site might be changed at any time, and (c) we're helping you for free and that makes us lazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-bootstrap-css/

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Comment: im wondering if i can just fix this with margins? take a look at my url, i guess i dont need the video to resize as long as it loads...